# equivalent of arraylist in android

Tags: android

I have the following json format :

"Student id"
"Name" "Semester"

I want to store this information in a listView or any other data structure in android. where i want to associate the id with name and semester

Is there anything which will be useful for me?

I am a newbie with android code snippets will be helpful.

Thanks,
Bhavya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `ArrayList` but you can't store all three elements pointing to each other. What you could do is create a class called `Student` and add `Students` to your list. Here's a quick example:

```
public class Student{
   private long id;
   private String name;
   private int semester;

   //add more methods here
}

List<Student> listOfStudents = new ArrayList<Student>
```

To parse your JSON, you could use the `google-gson` library from [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Ryan

Answer (score 1):

Well, since it's Java there's ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hasmap for that

```
class Student {
    long id;
    String name;
    int semester;
}
```

Parse JSON and make a objects of Student class and make a Map like this

```
Hasmap<String,String> arrStudents = new Hasmap<String, String>();
arrStudent.put("id",studentObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
class Student {
    long id;
    String name;
    int semester;
}
```

to store single person and ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Student> studentList;
```

to store more of them